# Why does Google recommend using CloudKMS application-layer encryption with Cloud Storage?

Tags: security, encryption, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-kms

On [this page](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/secret-management) about secret management on cloud.google.com, there is a paragraph that reads:

> Use application layer encryption using a key in Cloud KMS. With this
>   option, you implement encryption on objects or buckets in Cloud
>   Storage on top of existing Google encryption, using a key stored in
>   Cloud KMS. This is the recommended option.

Right below that, the next paragraph states that Google Cloud Storage encrypts data by default at rest:

> Use the default encryption built into the Cloud Storage bucket. GCP
>   encrypts customer content stored at rest, using one or more encryption
>   mechanisms. As the name implies, this encryption is available by
>   default and requires no additional action on your part.

For the uninitiated, why is application-layer encryption recommended here? If the GCS bucket(s) that store your objects are protected with IAM, and GCS already encrypts that data, what benefits are gained?

Answer (score 4):

It’s about *who* controls the keys, *when* the data is encrypted, *where* the data is encrypted, and *who* encrypts the data.

With GCS only, your data is encrypted at rest with keys Google stores and manages. You can’t revoke Google’s keys here. Additionally, the data is only protected at rest and in transit with TLS (but any person or app with the ability to terminate that TLS would see the secret in plaintext).

With GCS + KMS (often called “Customer Managed Encryption Keys” CMEK), data is encrypted before it’s written to GCS. GCS only stores the encrypted data (which is then encrypted again with keys Google manages). You, the customer, have full control over the rotation and revocation of those encryption keys. You can also use HSM-backed keys with Cloud HSM. Additionally, when following best practices, the data is protected in transit. Even if someone terminates TLS, the secret remains encrypted until something with IAM permission to  decrypt the value does so.

If you’re looking for an opinionated way to store secrets on GCP, check out [berglas](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/berglas).